# How Can I Get the Chart to Display the x-axis Ticklabels as Text Linked to the Source?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format the x-axis ticklables in my chart. The x-axis SeriesCollection data is text and it is formatted as text in the spreadsheet. The x data is read when the user checks a combobox. Yet the chart shows the labels as numbers. How can I get the chart to display the x-axis ticklabels as text linked to the source?

```
Sub CustomChartUpdate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Range, y1 As Range, y2 As Range
Dim points As Long
Dim xname As String, y1name As String, y2name As String
Dim countx As Integer, county As Long
Dim tempzoom As Single

countx = 0
county = 0

Set CustomChart = Sheets("Custom Chart")
Set EIRPSummary = Sheets("EIRP Summary")

'get last row of EIRP Summary
EIRPSummary.Select  'NOTE: the 'with-end with' statement does not work here
lastEIRPSummaryRow = EIRPSummary.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

'count the number of data points
points = lastEIRPSummaryRow - [ESDataRow1].Row + 1

With EIRPSummary
    If .OLEObjects("ESCaseNumBoxx").Object.Value = True Then
        countx = countx + 1
        Set x = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseNum].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseNum].Column))
        xname = "Case"
    End If
    If .OLEObjects("ESCaseDescripBoxx").Object.Value = True Then
        countx = countx + 1
        Set x = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseDescrip].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseDescrip].Column))
        xname = "Case Description"
    End If
    If .OLEObjects("Tx_AntBoxx").Object.Value = True Then
        countx = countx + 1
        Set x = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [Tx_Ant].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [Tx_Ant].Column))
        xname = "Tx Antenna"
    End If

If countx > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Check only one box for x and try again"
        GoTo TheEnd
    End If
End With

y1name = "nada"
y2name = "ditto"

With EIRPSummary

    county = 0
    If .OLEObjects("ESCaseNumBoxy").Object.Value = True Then
        county = county + 1
        If y1name = "nada" Then
            Set y1 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseNum].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseNum].Column))
            y1name = "Case"
        ElseIf y2name = "ditto" Then
            Set y2 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseNum].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseNum].Column))
            y2name = "Case"
        End If
    End If

    If .OLEObjects("ESCaseDescripBoxy").Object.Value = True Then
        county = county + 1
        If y1name = "nada" Then
            Set y1 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseDescrip].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseDescrip].Column))
            y1name = "Case Description"
        ElseIf y2name = "ditto" Then
            Set y2 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseDescrip].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseDescrip].Column))
            y2name = "Case Description"
        End If
    End If

    If .OLEObjects("Tx_AntBoxy").Object.Value = True Then
        county = county + 1
        If y1name = "nada" Then
            Set y1 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [Tx_Ant].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [Tx_Ant].Column))
            y1name = "Tx Antenna"
        ElseIf y2name = "ditto" Then
            Set y2 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [Tx_Ant].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [Tx_Ant].Column))
            y2name = "Tx Antenna"
        End If
    End If

If county > 2 Then
        MsgBox "Check a maximum of 2 boxes for y and try again"
        GoTo TheEnd
    End If
End With


'clear old data series
With CustomChart
    Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
End With

CustomChart.Activate

'read in x and y data
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .XValues = x
End With

With CustomChart
    .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=y1
    .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=y2
End With

'format series 2 (y1)
With CustomChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .name = y1name
    .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 1
    .MarkerStyle = 3
    .MarkerSize = 4
    .Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    .AxisGroup = 1
End With

'format series 3 (y2)
With CustomChart.SeriesCollection(2)
    .name = y2name
    .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 10
    .MarkerStyle = 8
    .MarkerSize = 4
    .Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    .AxisGroup = 2
End With

With ActiveChart
    'format title
    .HasTitle = True
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)

    With .ChartTitle
        .Text = y1name & "  &  " & y2name & "  vs  " & xname
        .Font.name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoFalse
        .Left = 40
    End With

'format x-axis
    .HasAxis(xlCategory) = True
    With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .HasTitle = True
        .MajorTickMark = xlNone
        .HasMajorGridlines = True
        .AxisBetweenCategories = False
        'Ticklabels font size and orientation below

        With .AxisTitle.Characters
            .Text = xname
            .Font.name = "Calibri"
            .Font.Bold = False
        End With

        With .Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
            .Transparency = 0
        End With

        With .MajorGridlines.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .DashStyle = msoLineDash
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(79, 129, 189)
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
            .Transparency = 0
        End With

        With .TickLabels
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .NumberFormatLinked = -1
            .Font.name = "Calibri"

            If points <= 35 Then
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Orientation = 0
            ElseIf points <= 50 Then
                .Font.Size = 9
                .Orientation = 0
            ElseIf points <= 60 Then
                .Font.Size = 7
                .Orientation = 0
            ElseIf points <= 75 Then
                .Font.Size = 6
                .Orientation = 90
            ElseIf points <= 100 Then
                .Font.Size = 6
                .Orientation = 90
            ElseIf points <= 200 Then
                .Font.Size = 6
                .Orientation = 90
            ElseIf points <= 300 Then
                .Font.Size = 6
                .Orientation = 90
            End If
        End With
    End With

    'format primary y-axis
    With .Axes(xlValue)
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = y1name
        .AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Bold = False
        .AxisTitle.Orientation = xlUpward
        .TickLabels.Font.name = "Calibri"
        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 9
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0"
        .MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
        .MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
        .MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .MinorUnitIsAuto = True
        .MajorTickMark = xlOutside

        With .MajorGridlines.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .DashStyle = msoLineDash
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(79, 129, 189)
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
            .Transparency = 0
        End With

        With .Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End With

    'format secondary y-axis
    With .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = y2name
        .AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Bold = False
        .AxisTitle.Orientation = xlDownward
        .TickLabels.Font.name = "Calibri"
        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 9
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0"
        .MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
        .MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
        .MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .MinorUnitIsAuto = True
        .MajorTickMark = xlOutside

        With .MajorGridlines.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .DashStyle = msoLineDash
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(79, 129, 189)
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
            .Transparency = 0
        End With

        With .Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End With


    'format legend
    .HasLegend = True
     With .Legend
        .Font.name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        .Left = 30
        .Top = 30
        .Width = 400
        .IncludeInLayout = False
    End With

    'set plot area size and position
    With .PlotArea
        .Height = 430
        .Width = 625
        .Top = 40
        .Left = 25
    End With
.ChartArea.Select
End With

tempzoom = ActiveWindow.Zoom
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
ActiveWindow.Zoom = tempzoom

TheEnd:

End Sub
```

Comment: How did you create the chart?  I can set x-axis labels using something like `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$10:$A$12"`

Comment: Set x = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseDescrip].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseDescrip].Column))

Comment: You can update your question to add code. I can't make much of your comment, since it looks just like setting a range variable: what do you do with `x` after that?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I have added the code where x is read in. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: you're adding your series incorrectly.

See below

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim xVals As Range, yVals As Range, yVals2 As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set cht = .ChartObjects(1).Chart
        Set xVals = .Range("A1:A8")
        Set yVals = .Range("B1:B8")
        Set yVals2 = .Range("C1:C8")
    End With

    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    'doesn't work!
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = xVals
    End With

    With cht
        .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=yVals
        .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=yVals2
    End With


    'works....
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = xVals
        .Values = yVals
    End With

    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = xVals
        .Values = yVals2
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the standard answer, which may assist others. But in my implementation, I cannot set xVals equal to a fixed range. The range must be chosen by the user by checking a combobox (there are actually dozens of them on the worksheet). I suppose I could try to write code that would construct the fixed range based on which combobox the user selects, and then assign x in the format you suggest.

Comment: "Standard answer" was all I could provide: your code seems incomplete so it's hard to replicate your exact problem. I used a fixed range as a shortcut, but I was assuming you'd confirmed that `x` was actually the range you expected, so there should be not difference in outcome due to that change.

Comment: I've added the complete code per your concern that it was incomplete.

Comment: yes it works! Much thanks for your patience and perseverance.